# copy files from the folder on one disk to the folder on another disk

Tags: devices, dd, cp

how to copy files from the folder on one disk to the folder on another disk use `cp` command?
(from the current directory on `sda2` to folder on `/dev/sdb3?`)

Comment: Are you asking because different disks are involved or are you asking how to `cp` files generally?

Comment: different disks are involved, built in disk and external usb hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Disks partitions are mounted in mountponits paths. You access them through these paths. For example, `/dev/sda5` can be mounted in `/media/user/MYDATA`. You can see the detailed information using tools like `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
...
├─sda6   8:6    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda7   8:7    0  39,7G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0   9,8G  0 part /media/user/SOMEPARTITION
sdb      8:16   0 298,1G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 298,1G  0 part /media/user/SOMEDISK
```

If a disk partition is not mounted, you won't be able to access the data in it, so first you have to mount it, using a command in terminal or a GUI like Disks.

Then you can run the `cp` command using the paths:

```
cp /home/user/somefile /media/user/MOUNTEDDISK
```